# JS recreate eventlistener

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm working with JQuery and ajax.

**SCENARIO:**
The scenario is the following. 
I have a table with different features and each row has it's own button to call "show data " function. With the first call I check some microservices that manipulated the origin data. If data is available ,I show a button for every manipulated data to show in a chart. Every Button gets a listener created in de success method of an ajax call. So there can be three scenarios:

> First: show data is called the first time. So there is no
>   Eventlistener created yet. In that case I create I new one for each
>   button.
>
> Second: Imagine I clicked a button to show the data in a chart. After
>   that, the chart gets closed. Now I want to show the same data again.
>   So my Eventlistener should stay the same and there should not be
>   another one added.
>
> Third: I click another feature in the table which might have data the
>   is manipulated differently or will be shown in another chart (e.g. pie
>   chart insted of flow chart.) So the scenario is pretty much like in
>   case one but now there is an old Listener to delete.

As a summary: I have to save the Eventlistener Object persistend when it gets createt because when case 3  turns up, I want to call removeEventlistener but I get an error that this object is not defined:

I'm a total noob in js.
This scenario results in the problem, that the eventarguments are not updated and you can see that the data output of listeners pops up for a second and gets overlayed by newer.
And when you do a few attemps, it ends in chaos where nothing fits. By this I mean the wrong data is shown in a wrong chart (one of an older event.).
So I wanted to delete the old listener and recreate it. 
Is this a possible solution or is there a better way to do it?

The whole funtion looks like this:

function showData(id,category,feature,date,caller,already_called){

```
    document.getElementById("originButtonDiv").style.visibility='visible';
    document.getElementById("squareButtonDiv").style.visibility='hidden';




    try{
        //show data again -> maintain listener
        if(old_already_called == 0 && already_called == 1){
            old_already_called = already_called;
        }
        //New feature choosen -> Delete old listener and create new one
        if(old_already_called == 1 && already_called == 0){
            $.ajax({
                  type:'GET',
                  url:"${path}/user/...
                  dataType:'text',
                  async: false,
                  success:function genTable(data){      

                            var originDataButton = document.getElementById("originDataButton");
                                //originDataButton.removeEventListener("click",_listener,true);
                                originDataButton.addEventListener("click", function _listener(){
                                originDataButtonClicked(id,category,feature,date);                                                              
                                }, true);



                  if(data.localeCompare("true")==1){                
                              document.getElementById("squareButtonDiv").style.visibility='visible';    
                                var squaredDataButton = document.getElementById("squaredDataButton");
                                    //squaredDataButton.removeEventListener("new_click",_squared_listener,true);                                                
                                    squaredDataButton.addEventListener("click",function _squared_listener(){
                                    squaredDataButtonClicked(id,category,feature,date);                     
                                    }, true);   
                        }
                  }
            });
            old_already_called = 0;
        }
    }
    catch{
        //first call --> create new Eventlistener
        $.ajax({
          type:'GET',
          url:"${path}/user/...
          dataType:'text',
          async: false,
          success:function genTable(data){      

                    var originDataButton = document.getElementById("originDataButton");
                        originlistener = originDataButton.addEventListener("click", function _listener(){
                        originDataButtonClicked(id,category,feature,date);  
                    }, true);





                  if(data.localeCompare("true")==1){                
                      document.getElementById("squareButtonDiv").style.visibility='visible';    
                        var squaredDataButton = document.getElementById("squaredDataButton");                                           
                            squaredDataButton.addEventListener("click",function _squared_listener(){
                            squaredDataButtonClicked(id,category,feature,date);                     
                            }, true);   
                }
          }
        });

        old_already_called = 1;
    }

}
```

**Update:**
I'm pretty sure now that the problem is the usage of ajax. I defined a logic tree for my use case because I have to detect whether an Eventlistener should be created, persist unchanged or deleted and recreated. I guess I can differentiate these circumstances in my code but the problem is, that I define the listener in the ajax `success` method. Between two calls the listener is undefined. So is there a possibility to save a listener object peristent on the client between to ajax calls so that I can delete it within future calls? I guess this would be the solution for my problem.

Comment: Did you update this because you're still looking for a solution (I'm asking because it's kind of an old question)? If so, you might want to add some html, or a *runnable* example. For at least I'm having trouble picturing what you're trying to do.

Comment: I updated my question: yes I reused this question because there was no answer all the time

Comment: To me it seems you're too focused describing what you do with those event listeners. But what is it that you're actually trying do do? React differently based upon whether some button has been clicked before, while at the same time trying to stay as [*dry*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) as possible?

Comment: Can you try to format your code properly and if possible make a testable snippet? Meantime, take a look at [this](http://api.jquery.com/on/), might give you an idea for solution.

Comment: I know there has to be a besster solution. But like I already said, I can't delete an already created listener between two ajax calls. Because the  _ listener Object is unknown.

Comment: @medTech That's not completely true. With jquery you could use [namespaced](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names) listeners, or simply keep a reference to the callback, which you can later use to delete it. But without anything to test, it's hard to come up with examples.

Comment: Thank you @Yoshi. With .on and .off it works. Here for everyone who's looking for the solution:
`$("#originDataButton").off();
         $("#originDataButton").on("click.show",{"param1":1,"param2":"myid"...},myCallbackfunction);`

`function myCallbackfunction(event){alert(event.data.param1)}`